# Why can't Activity.startActivity() find my activity, on API 33 only?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-api-33

I have a bug that only happens on API 33. Did something change? I mean, things definitely changed, but I made all the necessary updates. Did I miss one?

I have two apps: A and B. Let's call them `com.example.a` and `com.example.b`. They need to launch each other. As of API 33, when app A tries to launch app B, I get:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.b/com.example.b.DefaultLaunchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
```

`DefaultLaunchActivity` is defined in app B's manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.b.DefaultLaunchActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I also added the following to app A's manifest (required as of API 31):

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.b" />
</queries>
```

Finally, app A gets app B's launch Intent like this:

```
val intent = application.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.b")?.apply {
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
}
```

Adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER` doesn't help. App B gets the same error when it tries to launch app A.

To be clear, ***the code above works on API 32 but not API 33***. What changed?

Comment: For clarity: is your app targeting api level 33 as well?

Comment: Yes I'm targeting level 33, and min level 21.

Comment: Probably you need to add `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` manifest permission to get unfiltered installed packages

Comment: Have you tried manually creating a minimal explicit `Intent` to your desired activity, rather than using `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`?

Comment: @Zain that didn't help, but thank you

Comment: @CommonsWare that helped a lot, thanks. I was setting the `data` URI parameter, which has its own intent filter, but `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` was returning an `Intent` for the other intent filter. Post an answer and the bounty is yours.

Comment: Since I don't fully understand what worked for you, I suggest that you answer your own question. Regardless, I'm glad you got past the problem!

Comment: @BarryFruitman com.example.b is your custom app package?

Comment: getLaunchIntentForPackage() why does not work ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use intent as standard for this process. In addition to other answers you can use this technique.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.component = ComponentName("com.example.otherapp", "com.example.otherapp.ActivityName")
startActivity(intent)
```

`param 1` : OtherApp package name
`param 2` : activity you want to open

**Other App**

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" 
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, many things have changed.

You have to explicitly define in the `manifest` file packages of apps you are going to call, e.g.:

```
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.translate"/>
    </queries>
```

It was introduced in Android 11 (API 30). The observed behavior might be explained as it was introduced in API 30, but forced since API 33. Also others causes are possible. It will require more research to figure out a root cause.

[Ref. Android docs: queries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element)

[Ref. Android docs: Behavior changes: Apps targeting Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11)

**update**
I noticed you already use `queries` attribute, so an issue cause lays somewhere else

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I already tried that. Please re-read my question.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this later and had added **update** remark

Answer (score 0):

You have provided the package name of the destination app. Maybe, you can try adding these lines in the `query` tag.

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.b" />
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME,android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your A`ndroidManifest.xml` snippet, you've declared  activity with `android:exported="true"`, which should make the activity accessible from other apps.

Here some things to check and consider:

Use Explicit Component

To be explicit, you can use the `component` name when starting the `activity`. This ensures that Android can find the activity directly by its name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.b", 
"com.example.b.DefaultLaunchActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.a" />
</queries>
```

to AndroidManifest of app B?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` in the `<intent-filter>` for `com.example.b.DefaultLaunchActivity` for it to be able to receive implicit intents.:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element
[image: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element]

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleSend
[image: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleSend]